# Three colour gradient in livewallpaper

Tags: java, android, gradient, live-wallpaper

I am trying to create a gradient background for a live wallpaper. I can create it with two colours, but it won't allow me to have three.

Here is the code that I am currently using:

```
int[] colors = { Color.GREEN, Color.MAGENTA, Color.YELLOW };
float[] positions = {0, 1, 2};

LinearGradient gradient = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, height, colors,
    positions, android.graphics.Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
```

The result is a gradient from green to magenta, but without any yellow. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Here is an image of the result that I am currently getting:

[Image of Problem](http://celesteparker.files.wordpress.com/2013/08/screen012.png)

Comment: I am also facing same problem, any help would be appreciated...